# How to populate a custom textarea on changing of values in a custom dropdown field in sugarcrm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, sugarcrm

I am using SugarCRM 6.5.17 CE version. I have created a custom dropdown field which has values like amount, inquiry, total and according to selected option I want to populate a custom textarea field with different messages e.g. messages like Hello, Hi and Bye. I am confused here, so please help me out soon

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Show us the code, so we can see what you have tried and tell us where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use javascript to fetch the value from the dropdown list. Set different text in the textfield depending on the value in the dropdown. jQuery is loaded in all Sugar views by default in version 6.5.x.

A javascript file can be included in a quickcreateview, detailview or editview by adding the array key includes inside the form sub array.

```
'includes'=> array(
    array('file'=>'custom/modules/Accounts/CustomAccount.js'),
),
```